# css - align two divs left and right on same line

Tags: css, html

please see http://jsfiddle.net/UGmA2/7/
TIA

1 div container 2 divs.  Would like to put the second div on the first line but have it all the way to the right.

[image]
Any help would be appreciated,

```
<body background-color: #000000;>
    <div id="footer-container" style="width=980px;">
        <div id="div-left">
            <ul id="footer">
                <li id="text_separator"><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org">Text</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org/about"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" width="35" height="30" border="1"/></a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org/about"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" width="35" height="30" border="1"/></a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org/about"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" width="35" height="30" border="1"/></a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org/about"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" width="35" height="30" border="1"/></a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="div-left">
            <ul id="footer">
                <li id="text_separator"><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org">Text1</a>
                    <li id="text_separator"><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org">Text2</a>

                        <li id="text_separator"><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org">Text3</a>

                            <li id="text_separator"><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org">Text4</a> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: A helpful tip for your future web career, `ids` are unique and can only be used once on a page while `classes` are not unique. They can be used many times on the same page.

Answer (score 15):

Using same `id` repeatedly isn't a good idea, i change it all into `class`

here is the modification

```
<body >
  <div class="footer-container">
    <div class="div-left">
      <ul class="footer">
        <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org">Text</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org/about"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" width="35" height="30" border="1"/></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org/about"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" width="35" height="30" border="1"/></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org/about"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" width="35" height="30" border="1"/></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org/about"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" width="35" height="30" border="1"/></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="div-right">
      <ul class="footer">
        <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org">Text1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org">Text2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.org">Text3</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.stackflow.org">Text4</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    background-color: #000000;
}
.div-left{
    float:left;
    padding-left:10px;
}
.div-right{
    float:right;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.footer-container{
    height:40px;
    max-width:980px;
    border:1px solid salmon;
    padding-top:5px;
}
.footer {
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    border:solid 1px #E5E5E5;
}
.footer li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    padding-left:10px;
}
.footer a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#0088CC;
}
.footer li:nth-child(1) {
    text-decoration:none;
    height:30px;
    display:block;
    background-image:url('http://s7.postimg.org/w0nt224pj/bc_separator.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UGmA2/9/)

Answer (score 5):

change div id to class. you cannot have two ids on the same page. give the divs a width eg `width:45%` and float these items.

It appears the width of the first div is forcing the second to the line below.

Answer (score 3):

To the first div add a style to it like this `<div id="first-div" style="float-left;width:400px>`

For the second div like this `<div id="second-div" style="float-right;width:400px>`  hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using the style "float" will demand that you use the style "width" so measure out the width of the container to know the appropriate width to assign to the inner divs